# Debugging a custom Javascript MVC project

Tags: javascript, debugging, javascriptmvc

I have this huge project in my lap, that has been done in a custom Javascript MVC framework style. Each view is triggered via events through Javascript. It's the first time I am dealing with an application like this. In particular I am keen on understanding how I should approach debugging an application like this.

Comment: This is very broad. Can you narrow down your question? Are you interested in particular tools? Are you looking to solve some particular problem?

Comment: You take a debugger and you debug. That simple.

Comment: umm yes, firebug as the debugger. but the point of entry for this application is a JS file which in turn loads everything, if this was an HTML/CSS file, I could look up the elements and find out where everything is happening, but the web content is rendered dynamically in this case using a JS file, how do I troubleshoot

Comment: Regardless of the way the content is rendered - there *is* an HTML file that "starts that all" (unless it's server/fs side using Node or Rhino :)). That HTML file includes some bootstrap JS file that in turn loads all Views and binds all events in some fashion. Starting from that bootstrap would be a good place. In any case -  a bit more info would certainly help us help you.\

Comment: thanks, there is an HTML/PHP file that starts it all, index.php, and a main javascript file called DS.JS where all these views are loaded, there is a main model-view-controller and each subsequent component has a model-view-controller...it's all written in MooTools...what else should I describe